# How to reuse header definitions in RAML 1.0

Tags: api, http-headers, raml

I have a RAML 1.0 specification where I define multiple resources. Each of the resources do have the same set of headers.

What constructs of RAML do I need use to declare the headers once and reuse them in various resource definitions?

for e.g.

```
/read/records:
  post:
    description: api for reading records
    queryParameters: 
      table_name: string
    headers: 
            Authorization: 
                displayName: Authorization
                description: Basic authentication base 64 encoded string
                type: string
                required: true
            Tenant-Id: 
                displayName: Tenant-Id
                description: Tenant id for multi-tenant environments
                type: string
                required: true
            Content-type: 
                displayName: Content-type
                description: either xml or json
                type: string
                required: true
/adjust/records:
  post:
    description: api for editing records
    headers: 
            Authorization: 
                displayName: Authorization
                description: Basic authentication base 64 encoded string
                type: string
                required: true
            Tenant-Id: 
                displayName: Tenant-Id
                description: Tenant id for multi-tenant environments
                type: string
                required: true
            Content-type: 
                displayName: Content-type
                description: either xml or json
                type: string
                required: true
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**traits**](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#resource-types-and-traits) for that:

```
#%RAML 1.0
traits: 
  hasHeaders: 
    headers: 
      Authorization: 
        displayName: Authorization
        description: Basic authentication base 64 encoded string
        type: string
        required: true
      Tenant-Id: 
        displayName: Tenant-Id
        description: Tenant id for multi-tenant environments
        type: string
        required: true
      Content-type: 
        displayName: Content-type
        description: either xml or json
        type: string
        required: true
/read/records:
  post:
    is: ["hasHeaders"]
    description: api for reading records
    queryParameters: 
      table_name: string
/adjust/records:
  post:
    is: ["hasHeaders"]
    description: api for editing records
```

Comment: Amazing. This worked out with a minor change. I didn't have to give the [] for hasHeaders. It worked simply with is: hasHeaders. Are they needed for something else? Also what does the "is" construct indicate? Do traits work for generically declaring query parameters too ?

Comment: "Is" indicates where to apply the trait. When it's only one you can use without the "[]". You can apply more than one trait to a resource+verb, in that case you use an array "[]".

Answer (score 1):

Traits must represet a behavior and it´s apply by route and verb. For me with the header is apply to any route / verb you can define a resource type:

```
#%RAML 1.0 ResourceType
get?:
  headers: 
    Authorization: 
        displayName: Authorization
        description: Basic authentication base 64 encoded string
        type: string
        required: true
    Tenant-Id: 
        displayName: Tenant-Id
        description: Tenant id for multi-tenant environments
        type: string
        required: true
    Content-type: 
        displayName: Content-type
        description: either xml or json
        type: string
        required: true
post?:
  headers: 
    Authorization: 
        displayName: Authorization
        description: Basic authentication base 64 encoded string
        type: string
        required: true
    Tenant-Id: 
        displayName: Tenant-Id
        description: Tenant id for multi-tenant environments
        type: string
        required: true
    Content-type: 
        displayName: Content-type
        description: either xml or json
        type: string
        required: true
```